# Auto Save HTML file after contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to save the HTML file automatically after `contenteditable` is done. How to achieve this? My HTML file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample File editor</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>

    <body contenteditable="true">
        <div>Press keys here..<br/>
            <i>Sample Italic Text</i> and <b>Sample Bold Text</b> and so on...<br/>
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I'm expecting pure `javascript`.

Comment: Where do you want to save it?

Comment: maybe, maybe save to localStorage with onKeyPress event

Comment: I would like to save in the same location/overwrite with current HTML file. I have using `ubuntu OS` with chrome and firefox web browser.

Comment: "File > Save page as..." or [ctrl] + [s].

Comment: What would you say if any website was able to save random files on your hard drive without your action? How can the browser know that you are the author of this page and that you do trust yourself? You probably have already your hands on the keyboard anyway, is it really so hard to ctrl+s?

Comment: Thai would make for a really simple CMS if it was possible. But it isn't.

Comment: @NoobTW: Could you please advise how to do in onKeyPress event? I'm new in `javascript`...